# How to improve the time complexity of this algorithm to create comma separated digits?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity

**The problem:** I have an input which is a number as string. For example "123". I want to output a list of strings, which contains all possible ways, to separate the digits by commas. However, no element of the list should contain 3 digit numbers. Some examples:

Input: "1"

Output: ["1"]

Input: "12"

Output: ["12", "1,2"]

Input: "123"

Output: ["1,23", "12,3", "1,2,3"]

Input: "1234"

Output: ["12,34", "1,2,34", "1,23,4", "12,3,4", "1,2,3,4"]

Input: "12345"

Output: ["1,23,45", "12,3,45", "1,2,3,45", "12,34,5", "1,2,34,5", "1,23,4,5", "12,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5"]

I already have a function which does this:

```
public static List<String> getCommaSeparatedNumbers(String num) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = num.length();


        // If the number has less than 1 digit, there is only one possible way to format it
        if (n <= 1) {
            results.add(num);
            return results;
        }

        // Create an array to store all possible comma-separated numbers
        String[] possibilities = new String[(int) Math.pow(2, n - 1)];

        // Generate all possible comma-separated numbers using binary representation
        for (int i = 0; i < possibilities.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                sb.append(num.charAt(j));
                if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0 && j != n - 1) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
            }
            possibilities[i] = sb.toString();
        }

        // Filter out numbers with more than 2 consecutive digits
        for (String s : possibilities) {
            if (!s.matches(".*\\d{3,}.*")) {
                results.add(s);
            }
        }

        return results;
}
```

However, this function has a time complexity of ~ O(2^n * n). Unfortunately, I sometimes have numbers with many digits as inputs, where the function would simply take too long. **Is there a way to reduce the time complexity of this function?**

I thought of that you maybe you could use a recursive algorithm. For example, if you have as input "123", and you look at the first two digits, you can create "12" and "1,2". Now if you look at "12" you can add "3" or ",3". If you look at "1,2" you can only add ",3". Basically, if before the last digit, there is a comma, you can only add a digit with a comma, else you can add just the digit or a digit with a comma. I couldn't yet implement this algorithm however to test it.

Comment: allstrings("12345678") = (allstrings("1234567")+",8") + (allstrings("123456")+",78") + (allstrings("12345")+",678")

Comment: The size of the output is Fib() * , so you're anyhow looking at a time complexity of O(ⁿ) where =(1+√5)/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the output will be the determining factor.

We can produce the strings with this algorithm:

If the string has more than 2 characters, then at least one comma has to be inserted. The first comma could be inserted after the first character or after the second character. The substring that follows after the inserted comma can be treated with the same logic.

So for the number of strings in the output we observe this recurrence relation:

(1) = 1
      (2) = 2
      () = (−1) + (−2)

This is the Fibonacci sequence. And so the number of strings in the output is equal to Fib(), where  is the size of the input string.

This means the output consists of ⋅Fib() characters (not counting the commas), which is determining for the time complexity of an efficient algorithm. As Fib() is O(), where  [= (1+√5)/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Closed-form_expression), the best time complexity we can achieve is O().

Here is a recursive function that implements the above recurrence relation:

```
    public static List<String> getCommaSeparatedNumbers(String num) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = num.length();

        if (n == 1) {
            results.add(num);
        } else if (n == 2) {
            results.add(num);
            results.add(num.substring(0, 1) + "," + num.substring(1));
        } else if (n > 0) {
            for (String s : getCommaSeparatedNumbers(num.substring(2))) {
                results.add(num.substring(0, 2) + "," + s);
            }
            for (String s : getCommaSeparatedNumbers(num.substring(1))) {
                results.add(num.substring(0, 1) + "," + s);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```